# Linear system where I can not apply Cramer

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> I have to solve this linear system, 
>   $$
> \left\{ 
> \begin{array}{c}
> ax-2y+z=2 \\ 
> x-3y+2t=b \\ 
> x-6y-3z+8t=-2
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$

I am stucked because I do not know how to proceed. The number of unknowns is different from the number of equations so I can not apply Cramer. I thought to study the incomplete matrix of the system by applying Rouchè-Capelli but I do not know how to proceed since I should compare the incomplete matrix with the complete matrix of the system! How can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should consider $t$ as a parameter? In any case you can use Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Consider $x$, $a$, and $b$ as parameters and solve with respect to $(y,z,t)$:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
-2y+z+0t=2-ax \\ 
-3y+0z+2t=b-x \\ 
-6y-3z+8t=-2-x
\end{array}
\right.$$
Note that 
$$-3\cdot(-2y+z+0t)+4\cdot (-3y+0z+2t)=-6y-3z+8t.$$

Comment: Ok thank you for solutions